# aligning checkbox in HTML 5

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a login page in HTML.
no matter what i do, the checkbox and its text are not aliening together in a same line.
I want it to look like that: "[] text" instead of:
"[](going down a line) text".
I tried a lot of suggestions i saw in similar posts but nothing seems to works.

This is my code:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    padding: 50px;
}
.login {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 300px;
}
.login-screen {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.app-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
}

.login-form {
    text-align: center;
}
.control-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 250px;
    transition: border .5s;
}

input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #3498DB;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.btn {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background: #3498DB;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: 0.25s;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.errorMsg{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}
.LabeledCheckboxGroup label, .LabeledCheckboxGroup input {
    float: none; /* if you had floats before? otherwise inline-block will behave differently */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!--<script src="script/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="login">
    <div class="login-screen">
        <div class="app-title">
            <h1>Gridler</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" id="login-name">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked name ="IsHuman"> Human Player
            </div>

            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" href="#" onclick="process()">login</a>
            <!--errorMsg below will later be filed with script and ajax to show a msg when a name is already exist-->
            <p class="errorMsg" href="#"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks,
Maor

Comment: You're giving the element a width of 250px, remove it and it should work ok

Comment: you are added default width for all input tag... just add css for checkbox like this : `input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: auto;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the checkbox and its text inside a div.

Remove the width property from the checkbox.

Move the text into its own label.

set display: inline-block for both the checkbox and the label.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    padding: 50px;
}
.login {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 300px;
}
.login-screen {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.app-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
}

.login-form {
    text-align: center;
}
.control-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
     width: auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    transition: border .5s;
}

input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #3498DB;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.btn {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background: #3498DB;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: 0.25s;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.errorMsg{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}
.LabeledCheckboxGroup label, .LabeledCheckboxGroup input {
    float: none; /* if you had floats before? otherwise inline-block will behave differently */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!--<script src="script/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="login">
    <div class="login-screen">
        <div class="app-title">
            <h1>Gridler</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" id="login-name">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label><br/>
                <input type="checkbox" checked name ="IsHuman"> Human Player
            </div>

            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" href="#" onclick="process()">login</a>
            <!--errorMsg below will later be filed with script and ajax to show a msg when a name is already exist-->
            <p class="errorMsg" href="#"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
input.login-field {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the width for ALL inputs to 250px simply change

```
input {
text-align: center;
background-color: #ECF0F1;
border: 2px solid transparent;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 200;
padding: 10px 0;
width: 250px;
transition: border .5s;
}
```

To

```
#login-name {
text-align: center;
background-color: #ECF0F1;
border: 2px solid transparent;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: 200;
padding: 10px 0;
width: 250px;
transition: border .5s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code snippet, please have a look.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
body {
    font-family: Arial;
    background-color: #3498DB;
    padding: 50px;
}
.login {
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 300px;
}
.login-screen {
    background-color: #FFF;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px
}

.app-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #777;
}

.login-form {
    text-align: center;
}
.control-group {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

input {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #ECF0F1;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 200;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 250px;
    transition: border .5s;
}

input:focus {
    border: 2px solid #3498DB;
    box-shadow: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]
{
  width: 30px;
}

.checkbox {
   text-align: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  }

.checkbox label {
   vertical-align: top;
  }

.btn {
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    background: #3498DB;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: 0.25s;
    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.errorMsg{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: red;
}
.LabeledCheckboxGroup label, .LabeledCheckboxGroup input {
    float: none; /* if you had floats before? otherwise inline-block will behave differently */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <!--<script src="script/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Login.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="login">
    <div class="login-screen">
        <div class="app-title">
            <h1>Gridler</h1>
        </div>

        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="control-group">
                <input type="text" class="login-field" value="" placeholder="username" id="login-name">
                <label class="login-field-icon fui-user" for="login-name"></label>
              <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" checked name ="IsHuman"> <label>Human Player</label>
                </div>
                
            </div>

            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large btn-block" href="#" onclick="process()">login</a>
            <!--errorMsg below will later be filed with script and ajax to show a msg when a name is already exist-->
            <p class="errorMsg" href="#"></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```